# Проблема после перехода на PHP 7.1

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть функция для Wordpress

```php
function morkovin_get_srcset($width, $height, $array_srcset_width, $post_id, $attach_id, $def_src = "/images/no-photo.jpg") {
  if (function_exists('kama_thumb_src')) {
    $srcset_array = array();

    $array_srcset_width[] = $width;

    foreach($array_srcset_width as $item_width) {
      $item_height = $item_width * $height / $width;
      if ( kama_thumb_src('w='.$item_width.'&h='.$item_height.'&post_id='.$post_id.'&attach_id='.$attach_id) ) {
            $srcset_array[] = kama_thumb_src('w='.$item_width.'&h='.$item_height.'&post_id='.$post_id.'&attach_id='.$attach_id).' '.$nom.'x';
      } else {
        $srcset_array[] = kama_thumb_src('w='.$item_width.
          '&h='.$item_height.
          '&src='.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().$def_src).
        ' '.$item_width.
        'w';
      }
    }

    $src_result = 'srcset="'.implode(", ", $srcset_array).
    '"';

    return $src_result;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

На версии PHP 7.0 работала норм, но после перехода на PHP 7.1 - не работает.
Подскажите пожалуйста что в ней надо исправить?

Источник: http://www.sdelaysite.com/notes/ispolzovanie-srcset-dlya-adaptivnyx-izobrazhenij

Kama Thumbnail есть и обновлен до последней версии. И проблема не в нем, так как сам он работает. WP_DEBUG включен, но не выдает никакой ошибки, просто страница загружается только до того места где используется функция morkovin_get_srcset и все обрывается, в логе хостинга тоже ошибки не видно. Ставлю строку с функцией в коммент - и страница загружается без проблем

Функцию вызываю так:

```html
$w = 90;
$h = 60;
$item_srcset = morkovin_get_srcset( $w, $h, array(180, 270), $product_id );
```

Comment: Не работает __как__? Виден белый экран? Вместо картинки что-то иное? Может быть ваш сервер ребутается?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Ставлю на то, что `function_exists('kama_thumb_src')` возвращает `false`

Comment: Надо смотреть, дебажить, но одно главное: `PHP 7.0` **не совместим с** `PHP 7.1`. Теперь вы знаете что такое `legacy`, в данном случае ваш модуль :) http://php.net/manual/ru/migration71.php

Comment: Попробуйте обновить плагин "kama_thumb". И есть ли он вообще у вас в системе?

Comment: Приведённый вами код отмечается анализатором как валидный не только для 7.1, но и для 7.2. Последняя версия 2.8.6 плагина Kama Thumbnail тоже удовлетворяет требованиям 7.2. Проблема не там, где вы её ищете. Поясните, что значит - не работает. Какая ошибка в логах?

Comment: Выполнение прерывается - значит, 500. Чтобы ошибка 500 не отражалась в логах - так не бывает. У вас с логированием проблемы. Покажите, как выглядит вызов функции (который вы комментируете) и попробуйте вставить строки с error_log('что_нибудь') в функцию, чтобы определить строку, на которой скрипт падает.

Comment: После подстановки error_log выяснил что проблема в самой первой строке `function morkovin_get_srcset($width, $height, $array_srcset_width, $post_id, $def_src = "/images/no-photo.jpg")`, если удалить то что в скобках, то функция работает без ошибки, но без нужных данных

Comment: А вообще если удалить только $attach_id из скобок, то тоже работает, причем вроде правильно и без ошибок. $attach_id он там нужен вообще, или можно просто удалить и не париться?

Comment: $attach_id нужен в некоторых случаях

Answer (score -1):

решил проблему так - в стороке:

```html
function morkovin_get_srcset($width, $height, $array_srcset_width, $post_id, $attach_id, $def_src = "/images/no-photo.jpg") {
```

заменил $attach_id на $attach_id=''
теперь все работает как раньше

Comment: Ну и при чем тут php 7

Comment: на php 7.0 работало и так, а на 7.1 нет